# AWS Terraform: │ Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity:

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider:

> error validating provider credentials: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: 95e52463-8cd7-038-b924-3a5d4ad6ef03, api error InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid. with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"], on provider.tf line 1, in provider "aws": 1: provider "aws" {

I have only two files.

1. instance.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-068257025f72f470d"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
    
  tags = {
    Name = "instance_using_terraform"
  }
}
```

2. provider.tf

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "ap-east-1"
  access_key = "xxxx"
  secret_key = "xxxx/xxx+xxx"
}
```

[image: error image is here]

Comment: What is your TF code producing the error?

Comment: @Marcin tf code is planned and init successfully

Comment: any possibility for this issue, checked aws region and secret key, access key also.

Comment: How is it planned successfully when you get this error? Without the code you are using to configure the provider it is very hard to provide any help.

Comment: instance.tf : resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-068257025f72f470d"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags = {
    Name = "instance_using_terraform"
  }
}

Comment: providers.tf :provider "aws" {
    region = "ap-east-1"
    access_key = "xxxxxxxxx"
    secret_key = "xxxx/xx+xxxxxxxxx"
}

Comment: So you have not defined the `terraform` or `required_providers` blocks anywhere?

Comment: @MarkoE Thank you for the help ! No, I not declared any type of providers rather than providers. tf file. Now, Programme works well.

Answer (score 7):

May be Your passed AWS configure region is different from your terraform provider region
e.g: **us-east-1** in AWS configure, **us-east-1a** in terraform provider region.

Please change those regions to the same.

Comment: Daamn, thanks! in my case this was it. It's a surprisingly obscure error for a fairly simple error to happen. In my case it was because I was using us-west-3 instead of eu-west-3. So only 2 chars (one of them the same) was that was causing this.

Comment: In some cases it can happen when the AWS region is not enabled by default like `eu-south-1`

Answer (score 4):

In mycase this issue is because your system date/time is wrong.

Set Time for my centos8 OS through following command

timedatectl status
timedatectl set-time HH:MM:SS

it will throw error saying
"Failed to set time: NTP unit is active“if you already have set NTP service on your machine"

sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc true
sudo timedatectl set-ntp false
sudo timedatectl set-time "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
timedatectl list-timezones
sudo timedatectl set-timezone Europe/Zagreb
sudo timedatectl set-ntp yes

Answer (score 3):

In my test environment I was using the root users access and secret access key which did not work. After creating a dedicated user the error did not occur anymore.

In detail I did the following steps:

Created a user called terraform here
Created a new group Administrators with attached permissions Administrator Access by following the wizard
Copied access key and secret access key to ~/. aws /credentials
aws access key =xxx
aws secret access key=xxx
Created ~/.aws/config
[default]
region=us-west-2

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to use the default region specified for your AWS IAM account

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "eu-north-1" # < --- here 
  access_key = "**************"
  secret_key = "**************"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check .aws folder(CONFIG FILE).
Try this

```
aws sts get-caller-identity

{
    "UserId": "AIDAYMYFUCQM7K2RD9DDD",
    "Account": "111147549871",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::111147549871:user/myself"
}
```

Also show us your main.tf file and where and how you define access.

Comment: exactly i not userstood.... in the providers.tf file or other file need top change

Comment: Try this from cli.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Made mistake in the region where I declared entered the wrong namecode of region and access key - secret key '+' and '/' generating the error due to some symbols, you just need to try the new key till the access key contains only alphabetical string. (Symbols are lmao).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this issue, I found that the workspace I was working in had environment variables set in Terraform Cloud for the AWS credentials. These were taking precedence over my local credentials and needed to be refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to update my provider version. Went through all the suggestions here, but none worked. My required_providers version was 4.67.0, but updating it to 5.0 on my .tf file required I update the locked dependency selections to match a changed configuration by running "terraform init -upgrade" command. And that did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might hit this error

```
Error: configuring Terraform AWS Provider: validating provider credentials: retrieving caller identity from STS: operation error STS: GetCallerIdentity, https response error StatusCode: 400 ... api error IncompleteSignature: ....  not a valid key=value pair
```

Check that your credentials file doesn't contain any trailing spaces, eg at the end of lines. AWS is quite happy to strip these and works fine, Terraform doesn't!  Took me way to long to track that one down.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was demonstrating with the Credentials and files I downloaded from GitHub. I didn't change the credentials to my own. (Both the Access Key and the Secret Key).
I changed it and it worked! I was on it for several weeks trying to figure what could have happened.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because I had disabled the regions in the account I was trying to generate a plan. To see the list of enabled/disabled regions, you can go here: https://us-east-1.console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?region=us-east-1#/account?AWS-Regions

Answer (score -1):

In my case, the error was because I didn't have a default configuration declaration. When I created it, it all worked.

Comment: Please elaborate what was missing and what was setup.